# Add a css class to an element after clicking on it

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, umbraco

I'm trying add a `css` class to an element after clicking on it.
But I couldn't do it.
My target of this action is that, in my first level of menu when I click to an element, it be show with another color.

For example visit this link.

http://www.templatemonster.com/demo/50935.html

May this problem occurred because of refreshing the page after clicking! I'm not sure.

How can I do it?

(I've used ASP.NET and Umbraco CMS)

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function (evt) {
    $("[class*='firstLevelOfMenu'] ").click(function (event) {
        event.stopPropagation(); // stops click event from bubbling up from child
        $(this).addClass('current-menu-item page_item page-item-203 current_page_item');
    });
})

</script>
```

**MyHelpers.cshtml:**

```
@helper Navigation(int parentId, int depthNavigation = 3)
{
IPublishedContent parent = Node.ContentCache.GetById(parentId);
if (parent.Level <= (depthNavigation - 1) &&        parent.GetPropertyValue("UmbracoNaviHide").Equals(false) &&    parent.Children().Count() > 0)
{
if (parent.Level > 1)
{
        <ul style="visibility: hidden; display: none;" class="sub-menu">
            @foreach (IPublishedContent child in parent.Children())
            {
                if (child.Level <= depthNavigation &&    child.GetPropertyValue("UmbracoNaviHide").Equals(false))
                {
                    <li class="menu-item menu-item-type-post_type menu-item-   object-page">
                        <a href="@child.Url">@child.Name</a>
                        @Navigation(child.Id, depthNavigation)
                    </li>
                }
            }
        </ul>
    }
    else
    {
        foreach (IPublishedContent child in parent.Children())
        {
            if (child.Level <= depthNavigation && child.GetPropertyValue("UmbracoNaviHide").Equals(false))
            {
                <li id="menu-item-@child.Id" class="firstLevelOfMenu 
                    menu-item
                     menu-item-type-post_type
                     menu-item-object-page">

                    <a href="@child.Url">@child.Name</a>
                    @Navigation(child.Id, depthNavigation)
                </li>
            }
        }
    }
}
else
{
    foreach (IPublishedContent child in parent.Children())
    {
        if (child.Level <= depthNavigation && child.GetPropertyValue("UmbracoNaviHide").Equals(false))
        {
            <li>
                <a href="@child.Url">@child.Name</a>
                @Navigation(child.Id, depthNavigation)
            </li>
    }
}
}
}
```

Comment: There is easier way to select element by class name. Just use it like this:
`$('.firstLevelOfMenu')`. Dot in front of your class name determines that you want to select element by class name. Try it out.

Comment: After the click, is the user redirected to a new page?

Comment: Since this is Umbraco, you can just check the current page URL to see if it contains the parent (or topmost in tree) URL, and if so, add the `current` class to it. For example, the URL `http://example.com/products/hats/safari?color=white` contains the substring `http://example.com/products/hats` so it would be easy to add `class="current"` to the "Hats" navigation item in the Razor markup based on that match. This is of course dependent on your hierarchy but hopefully gives you something to build on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DOM changes are not persistent. Happens exactly what you say: `this problem occurred because of refreshing the page after clicking`.

To have this behaviour you have to make the changes on page load instead of making the changes on clicking a link, because those changes will be lost when a new page is loaded.

You have to read the URL, "discover" what link has to be changed and do the proper actions.

For example, lets say you have 3 links on `http://exampledomain.com`, pointing each one this way:

- Link 1: `http://exampledomain.com/about-us`
- Link 2: `http://exampledomain.com/buy-something`
- Link 3: `http://exampledomain.com/find-my/dog`

Then, you should have this script:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    /* This will get the path part of the
     * URL (The string after the domain) and
     * split it into an array .*/
    var path = window.location.pathname.split("/");

    /* The we will remove the starting / if there's any */
    if (path.length > 1) {
        path.splice(0, 1);
    }

    /* We check if there's actually a path */
    if (path.length > 0) {
        return;
    }

    /* And then, we check for the different links */
    switch(path[0]) {
        case "about-us":
            $("#link1").addClass('yeah');
            break;
        case "buy-something":
            $("#link2").addClass('yeah');
            break;
        case "find-my":
            $("#link3").addClass('yeah');
            break;
    }
});
```

Comment: I didn't implement exactly your code but I got a good idea! I passed currentPageId to Navigation() method and then based on I added my class to element.
THANKS!